# How to Change Form Design Preview to Windows 8 Theme

Tags: windows-8, windows-7, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013, (since my PC is Windows 8), I want my form designer to  look like Windows 8 Windows. Instead, it has the Windows 7 Style, as seen in the images below. How am I to get the preview to have the Windows 8 Style instead of the Windows 7 Style?

[image: Windows 8 Window style]

[image: Windows 7 Window style]